# C# random - if statement only output = -1

Tags: c#, random

I'm trying to make my program output either 1 or -1 this is my code so far and its only output is -1.  It's not random at all.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int L = rnd.Next(0, 1);
if (L == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(-1);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(1);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

The second argument [`Random.Next(int, int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx) gives an *exclusive* upper bound. So you're saying you want an integer greater than or equal to 0, and less than 1. That doesn't give a lot of scope for numbers other than 0 :)

From the documentation:

> **Return Value**
>   Type: System.Int32
>   A 32-bit signed integer greater than or equal to minValue and less than maxValue; that is, the range of return values includes minValue but not maxValue. If minValue equals maxValue, minValue is returned.

You should also read my [article on randomness](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx) to avoid other common problems.

Comment: Oh ok, what would your suggestion be to change?

Comment: @user2966573: I suggest you think about it for yourself, rather than me spoonfeeding you :) Think about what upper bound you actually want.

Comment: Oh so like between 0 and 3? so the only ones are 1 and 2?

Comment: @user2966573: No, because the lower bound is *inclusive*. Read the documentation carefully.

Comment: @JonSkeet +1 for your article that suggests using cryptographic randomness....MANY people don't quite get that the built in random function isn't very good.

Answer (score 7):

`rnd.Next(0, 1)` returns a value `i` in the range `0 <= i < 1`. The only such value is `0`.

Take a look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx):

> **minValue**
>
> Type: System.Int32
>
> The inclusive lower bound of the random number returned.
>
> **maxValue**
>
> Type: System.Int32
>
> The exclusive upper bound of the random number returned. maxValue must be greater than or equal to minValue.

Note that the `minValue` is *inclusive* and the `maxValue` is *exclusive*. So, in more general terms, this overload of `next()` returns values in the range:

```
minValue <= i < maxValue
```

In case you are not aware of the terminology, in the context of inequalities, *inclusive* means `<=` or `>=` and exclusive means `<` or `>`.

<sub>Well, the inequality above is not strictly true in case minValue == maxValue but I choose to neglect that corner case in the sake of a cleaner exposition.</sub>

Comment: Too bad. Jon Skeet is here ;)

Comment: @Adam Feel free to upvote mine and not his!!  ;-)  Well, Jon's answer is very good as always (link to his article is very sound). I'm only kidding about.

Answer (score 0):

Random.Next with 2 arguments returns value min <= < max

so, you need values 0 or 1, simple change your code to: `rnd.Next(0, 2);` - this will return either 0 or 1

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to make my program output either 1 or -1 this is my code so far and its only output is -1. It's not random at all.

You could use a simple algorithm instead:

```
int L = (rnd.Next (1, 3) * 2) - 3;
Console.WriteLine(L);
```

Comment: Honestly I find that less readable than the original, just glancing at it I have no idea what your code does, I have to stop and think to see it. The performance difference between your version and the original is likely negligible but the original makes it very clear what is being done.

Comment: I don't see anything in my answer about it being more readable.  It's simply a different approach. Which, while the efficiency difference is small it is there none the less.